# Check whether a path is accessible using the posix module

Tags: python, posix

How can I check if given path is accessible using the posix module in Python, what I mean by accessible, is that I can make changes to any file in this folder, so I have for example root permissions, also, I want to know which file I cannot access.

I have looked in the `access` function, but I don't really understand it and how can I use it and how can it help me.

```py
import posix

result = posix.access('/home/user/Desktop', 1) # what does that number mean ?
print(result) # True or False
```

Answer (score 2):

From the python docs for the posix module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/posix.html#module-posix

> Do not import this module directly. Instead, import the module os, which provides a portable version of this interface

You can find more information about os.access here, including an example: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.access

However please note what the example says:

> Using access() to check if a user is authorized to e.g. open a file before actually doing so using open() *creates a security hole*, because the user might exploit the short time interval between checking and opening the file to manipulate it. It’s preferable to use EAFP techniques.

If you still want to just use .access, your code would be like this:

```
import os

result = os.access('/home/user/Desktop', os.F_OK) 
print(result) # True or False
```

second param is mode:

- os.F_OK − Value to pass as the mode parameter of access() to test the
  existence of path.
- os.R_OK − Value to include in the mode parameter
  of access() to test the readability of path.
- os.W_OK Value to include
  in the mode parameter of access() to test the writability of path.
- os.X_OK Value to include in the mode parameter of access() to
  determine if path can be executed.

Comment: `result` Will return True only if ALL files in the given path can be writable for example ?